# What is configuration avoidance option to find exising task in Gradle's Kotlin DSL?

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Using configuration avoidance API: the way to create a new task and configure it:

```
val someLongTaskName by tasks.registering {
  // configure action here
}
```

while the way to configure an existing task:

```
val anotherVeryLongTaskName = tasks.named("anotherVeryLongTaskName") {
  // configure action here
}
```

In the latter case I'd rather like not to repeat myself and use something similar to:

```
val anotherLongTaskName = by tasks.naming {
  // configure action here
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not need the `val anotherLongTaskName`.

So You will not repeat your self in cases where you will write:

```
tasks.named("anotherVeryLongTaskName") {
  // configure action here
}
```

Comment: In my case I do need the val to reference it later.

Comment: @AlexanderVasiljev - yeah sorry forgot to mention that in case you do need the val I am not familiar with a way.